# node-rddkafka batch consume optimization

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, consumer

I am using node-rdkafka to consume from my kafka topics ( with 1 partition) and try to ingest the data that I consume to a database.
My code is working well but I wonder how to optimize this code, every time I read from Kafka, I see that the code treats each message seperatly.
I am curious to know how I can send a batch of data together to a database.
Can you please give me a little idea about that ?

let counter = 0;
const numMessages = 5;

```
    stream
        .on('ready', () => resolve(stream))
        .on('data', function(data) {
            // Output the actual message contents
            counter++;

            //committing offsets every numMessages
            if (counter % numMessages === 0) {
                console.log('calling commit');
                stream.consumer.commit(data);
            }

            // Output the actual message contents
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            winston.debug(data.value.toString());
            winston.debug(new Date().getTime());
        });
    stream.connect();
```